# Compare two sheets each rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, compare

I have two sheets, one with old data and new one. the length of the row is A to R. I want to compare each row with specific id which one is changes from the old data.

this is the expected outcome

```
On Sheet1 (old data)
Col A       | Col B      | Col C
1001        | My Val 1   | My Val 5 
2001        | My Val 2   | My Val 6 
3001        | My Val 3   | My Val 7
4001        | My Val 4   | My Val 8  

On Sheet2 (new data)
Col A       | Col B          | Col C      | Col D
1001        | My New Val 1   | My Val 5   | Changes
2001        | My New Val 2   | My Val 6   | Changes
4001        | My Val 4       | My Val 8   | No Changes
```

I'm trying to use this formula

```
=INDEX('30/11/2023'!B2:B,MATCH(A2:A,'30/11/2023'!A2:A))=B2
```

but it compare different row when there is some row that was deleted. so it doesn't compare the right data(row)

[id in sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v1fD.png)
[id in sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9oY7.png)

I want to compare the rows (A to R) with same ID from two different sheets. Help me to make the proper formula for this case
thank you

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: I think I have a solution, but I need to see how it aligns with your expectation of a successful outcome.

Comment: that's the expected outcome in the first place

Comment: That doesn’t compute. Aren’t you saying sheet#1 _is_ the old data and sheet#2 _is_ the new data. So what does the outcome look like?

Comment: there is col D in the sheet2, it checks if the rows was updated or not, i just need a formula to compare the row with exactly same id and says that it was "changed" or "no changes"

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in Cell S2 of Sheet 2(the new data sheet):

```
=map(  
  byrow(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, oldD!A2:R, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}, ))),
    lambda(x,textjoin("",true,x))),
  byrow(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, A2:R, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}, ))),
    lambda(x,textjoin("",true,x))),
  lambda(old,new,if(exact(old,new),"No Changes","Changes"))
)
```

---

**LOGIC**

- `byrow(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, oldD!A2:R, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}, ))), lambda(x,textjoin("",true,x))`

  - look up the ID in Column A of Sheet 2 (New data),
  - return the values in Columns B to R from Sheet 1 (Old data)
  - concatenate (`TEXTJOIN`) the result
- `byrow(INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A4, A2:R, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}, ))), lambda(x,textjoin("",true,x))),`

  - ditto for the values on the Sheet2
- `lambda(old,new,if(exact(old,new),"No Changes","Changes"))`

  - compare the two strings.

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: Changes]